# Get timezone list in vb.net 2003

Tags: vb.net, timezone

Is there any way to get timezones list using vb.net 2003 ..I want to get timezone list and put it on combobox controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See  [TimeZoneInfo Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx#Y228).

Here is the C# code :-

```
public static void Main()
{
    ReadOnlyCollection<TimeZoneInfo> timeZones = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();

    foreach (TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo in timeZones)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", timeZoneInfo.DisplayName);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: i think dotNet framework 1.1 is not supported the System.TimeZoneInfo class

Comment: Yeah true , its on and above .net 3.5

Comment: Did u consider http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezone%28v=VS.71%29.aspx ?

Answer (score 1):

I have a collection of Time Zones as an XML doc here

https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=95e9849b11bde22f&sc=photos&uc=1&id=95E9849B11BDE22F%21120#cid=95E9849B11BDE22F&id=95E9849B11BDE22F%21120

This collection has many not available in .Net.